# How can I get AngularJS to bind an input field to an external change?

Tags: angularjs

At the moment I have an input field with the following directive:

```
ng-model="event.location"
```

I also have the input field attached to a Google Maps auto complete script. By way of example, if my user types "apa", the Google auto complete list will come up and there is the option of clicking "Apartments". However, the String "Apartments" does not bind to my variable and the "location" variable only contains the String "apa". How can I get AngularJS to bind to the full location once the user selects an option from Google Maps?

Update: It's just a one liner for Google Maps

```
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('location-text'));
```

Although I'm sure a lot more is happening behind the scenes

Comment: I think that without including some code that demonstrates more of how google maps interacts with your angular code would be a good idea. I would guess a very small subset of potential answereres have actually integrated with Google Maps. Right now the only thing I could provide is a vague "you need to use `$scope.$apply` when doing changes to your models from outside an Angular context", which may or may not be what you need.